# How do I remove matching lines from one text file using another?

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to remove matching lines from one text file using another. For example, `fired.txt` contains:

```
Jason
Candice
Brent
Tom
```

And I want to remove matching lines from `workers.txt`, which currently looks like this:

```
Andrew
Tommy
Peter
Jason
Brent
Sasha
Tom
Candice
```

So, in the end, it would remove the entire line if it matches exactly, so it would look like this:

```
Andrew
Tommy
Peter
Sasha
```

I am using macOS Sierra, btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short ***grep*** approach:

```
grep -xvf fired.txt workers.txt
```

The output:

```
Andrew
Tommy
Peter
Sasha
```

---

*grep* options:

- `x` - Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line
- `v` - Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines
- `f` (`--file=file`) - Obtain patterns from `file`, one per line

Comment: If the `F` (`--fixed-strings`) option is added, the match will be literal instead of interpreted as a regular expression. This is useful if the strings to match contain brackets, braces, parenthesis or other special regex character.